# Sending Emails with Attachments

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, email, attachments

We have a requirement to have automation of sending emails with Attachments. For example the ff. scenario:

1. User requests for a document which user does not have access.
2. Then some approvals happen and once approved
3. Once approved, workflow will send the document as an attachment to the user

I don't think out of the box SharePoint Designer workflow can do this.

My current thinking is we can use Custom Visual Studio workflow to download the document and then send an email as attachments using custom code. However, I am concerned with large files or large number of files. Is there a memory limitation or it might slow down the performance of our server if the workflow email attachment constantly runs?

Or are there any better approaches to this one?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the budget then you might want to use [Nintex](http://nintex.com/) or [K2](http://www.k2.com/en/index.aspx) or migrate to SP Online and use MS Flow.

Or

Using SSOM, you can write a function (inside event receiver/ VS workflow) to send an email
as shown in [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96158/how-to-send-email-with-attachments-in-sharepoint-2013) link.

Comment: Thanks harshal. I don't think we have the budget for it. Seems SSOM is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the resources already mentioned, there are free resources on codeplex, such as [sharepointstuff](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sharepointstuff), which has a "Send Email With Attachment" activity you can download and install. Once installed, it can be used like any other action within sharepoint designer workflows.